# Varnish SMS allocation request generate HTTP 503

Tags: redhat, varnish

Sometimes my application return a HTTP 503 error to a client. The only clue I have is that when it happen, Cacti reports a peak of Varnish SMS Allocation requests.

After some research I may have allocated too much RAM to Varnish compared to what my VM had. So I added 2GB. Varnish has been reload since, but not restarted.

Now the error happens rarely, but still.

- 0 error in application log
- 0 error in apache log

Here the cacti graph with the SMS peak:
http://s29.postimg.org/94bu3vvd3/varnish_SMS.png

varnish-3.0.4 on RHEL 6.3

Varnish start parameters :

/usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/rc_platform.vcl -T xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:6082 -t 120 -w 1,1000,120 -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,6G

Interesting part of varnishstat

```
SMA.s0.c_req            14736881         2.26 Allocator requests
SMA.s0.c_fail            4190399         0.64 Allocator failures
SMA.s0.c_bytes      353887517876     54362.00 Bytes allocated
SMA.s0.c_freed      347445180586     53372.37 Bytes freed
SMA.s0.g_alloc            311300          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.s0.g_bytes        6442337290          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.s0.g_space            113654          .   Bytes available
SMA.Transient.c_req     15771681         2.42 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail           0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes 910056978442    139797.31 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed 910056853513    139797.29 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc           52          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes       124929          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space            0          .   Bytes available
```

I have a 10GB VM and 6 are allocated to Varnish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really high SMA.s0.c_fail count. So, Varnish tries to allocate memory and fails. You can have Varnish be more aggressive by upping the nuke_limit, which is the number of objects Varnish can kill when trying to free memory.

You need to restart for changes to memory settings to take effect. However, I suggest having some more memory available to your server. Giving Varnish more memory is usually cheap and smart.

To avoid failing a request Varnish will allocate transient memory to store an object. The transient memory storage is unbounded, which means it can potentially bring a server down if it being overused. You might limit it if you want to.